# Why does tsc (typescript) give me errors "Cannot find type definition file for xyz"?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I read some docs and tried a whole bunch of different things in the tsconfig.json, but no matter what I still get these errors.  Here is the simplest version of my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./packages/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "webpack.config.js",
  ]
})
```

All my source code is in /packages, and there is only source code there.  The strange thing is the errors I get (below) seem to have nothing to do with my project (the packages contain react-native source code).

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'anymatch'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'body-parser'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'connect'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'connect-history-api-fallback'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'express'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'express-serve-static-core'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'http-proxy'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'http-proxy-middleware'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'mime'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'range-parser'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'serve-static'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'source-list-map'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'uglify-js'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack-dev-server'.

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack-sources'.
```

Thanks for any assistance or insight!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the @types/ packages for these and I believe your errors will go away.